# Trying to run a git command in a child process that requires pipes

Tags: javascript, git, unix, child-process, spawn

I need to run a git branch command in a child process, but I want to get only the currently checked out branch. This command work in terminal:

```
git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2
```

I have a number of posts that are trying to do something similar, but my understanding of Unix commands isn't good enough to get a solution.

I have tried this among a number of other things:

```
spawn("git", ["branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2"], opts)
```

this is what I . get from stderr:

> git: 'branch | grep * | cut -d ' ' -f2' is not a git command. See 'git
>   --help'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Shell commands have a lot of syntax: `a | b | c` doesn't mean "run the command `a | b | c`" but rather "run the command `a`, with a bunch of glue that makes it pipe output; run the command `b`, with a bunch of glue that makes it read the earlier piped output as its input, and pipe its output; and run the command `c`, with a bunch of glue that makes it read `b`'s piped output".

You could duplicate all of this glue in your code, but `git branch | grep \* | cut -d ' ' -f2` is the wrong way to do this in the first place.  Instead, use one of these two commands:

```
git symbolic-ref --short HEAD
git rev-parse --abbrev-ref HEAD
```

The difference between these two commands is that the first one *fails* (with an error message) *if there is no current branch*.  The second one prints `HEAD` for this case.  This case occurs when `HEAD` is "detached", i.e., the repository *has no current branch*.

The `git branch | grep \* | cut ...` sequence *succeeds but prints `(HEAD`* for this detached-HEAD case, and `(HEAD` is not useful.